# Keycloak adapter cannot found loggin properties file

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I'm using the last keycloak version (1.6.1) in Windows 7, I'm following its official blog http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/10/getting-started-with-keycloak-securing.html .All is working until the installation of the client adapter into WildFly server. When I try `bin/jboss-cli.sh -c ':shutdown(restart=true)'` I got this message:

`Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:/d/Projects/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/jboss-cli-logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundException: \d\Projects\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin\jboss-cli-logging.properties (The system can not find the path specified))` . Off course I have the file in the path.

Comment: why are you using bash scripts (.sh) on windows? Just use .bat files and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, now is working without problem @ctomc . Thanks.